# Issues with iptables & google recaptcha

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, iptables, captcha

I am running a cloud server with Ubuntu 20.04 on it, which is hosting a forum. This forum uses Google's reCaptcha to protect new registrations.

However, when I have my iptable rules in place, the reCaptcha will time out. If I disable the rules, everything will be fine.

I am no expert in this, the rules in place are mainly gathered from hardening guides ([1](https://raiyanlive.wordpress.com/2016/09/02/hardening-server-security-using-iptables/), [2](https://itpeopleblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/10/hardening-server-security-using-iptables-2/)) this is what I am having:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 22,http,https,submission state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
DROP       all  -f  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  -f  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports 22,http,https,submission state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
```

So, if I change chain default policies to ACCEPT, everything works, so the error must be in one of the above rules. However, HTTP/HTTPS is definately enabled, and googling for additional ports yields no more ports used by reCaptcha.

Could anyone help me out here to make it work?